# Disabling the last tab cursor movement in a Sublime Text snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet, sublime-text-plugin

I'm looking for a way to disable the last tab cursor movement in a Sublime Text snippet.

For clarity I'm referring to the last press of the tab key that brings you to the end of the snippet.  In the below example, with '|n' representing each cursor position, I do not want to be moved to cursor position 2.

```
{% block |0 %}
    |1
{% endblock |0 %}|2
```

The slight inconvenience this causes is having to exit/cancel the snippet auto completion before I can use Emmet completions at cursor position 1.

Any feedback is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you’ve set `insert_final_tabstop` option to `true`: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings#L71

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe I explained my issue well enough. In this example, the snippet is from the Djaneiro plugin for a set of Django block template tags. I was able to find an acceptable work-around by looking at your repository though. Ctrl+E will allow me to expand an Emmet snippet when Sublime wants to do something else with the Tab key. Thanks for the response, your plugin is great.

Comment: Then your question is incorrect: it has nothing in common with Emmet, it’s just default ST snippets, provided by Djaneiro package.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said "Sublime Text snippet" twice, and only mentioned Emmet as the motivation for a work-around. Apologies for not being clearer.

Answer (score 9):

Just found this answer on the [sublime forums](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5742). If no `$0` or `${0}` is specified, it seems to default to the end of the snippet. If you change your snippet to:

```
{% block $1 %}
$0
{% endblock $1 %}
```

Then you will not get the last tab in the above `|2` position. Oddly enough, the `$1` will still come first.

Comment: I just want to hug you forever <3